# Omit aggregate function

Tags: mysql

According to w3schools group by needs an `aggregate_function(column_name)`.

```
SELECT column_name, aggregate_function(column_name)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name operator value
GROUP BY column_name
```

What it will happen if you commit this aggregate_function?

Thanks

Comment: Yes. it returns something really strange. It is not a sum or average or min or max

Comment: Offtopic: stop learning from W3Schools, their website is full of garbage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for best practice, do not use `GROUP BY` unless you are using an aggregate function. MySQL is unique in that it allows you to specify additional columns without using aggregates. This is not found in other DBMS's.

> MySQL extends the use of `GROUP BY` to permit selecting fields that are not mentioned in the GROUP BY clause.

The other effect that `GROUP BY` has is it's sorting property.

> If you use `GROUP BY`, output rows are sorted according to the `GROUP BY` columns as if you had an `ORDER BY` for the same columns.

If you do not include any aggregate functions, it will most likely show the `DISTINCT` values of the grouped column.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on MySQL version and ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY mode, it either rejects the query or picks any value from each group (it is undefined which one it chooses).

Here is a thorough description on this: [MySQL Handling of GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html)